# How to join on overlapping dates but keep preceding records

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables as such

Table A:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-07 |
| 1 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-08 |
| 1 | 2020-01-08 | 2020-01-09 |
| 1 | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-10 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-11 |

Table B:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-04 |
| 2 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-06 |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-07 |

By default the rows in table A are preferred over the rows in table B. I need to identify the rows which have overlapping dates. i.e. I want a resulting table which looks like this

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-07 |

My current strategy is

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT b.*
      FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a
        ON ((b.start_date <= a.end_date) AND (b.end_date >= a.start_date))
```

However this gives me a record (due to the one overlapping date) which I don't want to be returned:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-06 |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-07 |

I'm doing this in Spark SQL if that helps at all.

Comment: I wonder if adding an additional to the condition works? `ON ((b.start_date <= a.end_date) AND (b.end_date >= a.start_date)) AND (b.end_date != a.start_date))

Answer (score 0):

This assumes start and end dates are inclusive. Change >= to > if start is inclusive and end is exclusive.

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON b.start_date >= a.start_date -- start after A is started
  AND b.start_date <= a.end_date -- start before A is finished
```